# how to upload packages in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Hi this is Ashwaq
i have apex class and apex page and these two things i have to upload in to package while i am uploading this package i am getting this error"No testMethods found in the selected Apex code for the package".so kindly let me know this solution and give me reply asp.

apex class:

```
public global virtual class SendEmailToFeedback
{ 
    public String items { get; set; }
    Opportunity opportunity;
    public String subject{ get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public String lid { get; set; }
    public String response {get; set;}
    List<Opportunity> Opp;
    public PageReference cancel() 
    {
        return null;
    }   
    public List<Opportunity> getOpp()
    {
       if(Opp== null)
         {
           lid = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('name');
           Opp= [Select o.Name,o.Email__c from Opportunity o where o.id =:lid];
         }
        return Opp;
    }
    public PageReference send() 
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String addresses;
        if (Opp[0].Email__c != null)
        {
            addresses = Opp[0].Email__c;

                if (Opp[0].Email__c != null)
                {
                    addresses += ':' + Opp[0].Email__C;
                    String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);
                    email.setSenderDisplayName('THYLAKSOFT LLC');
                    email.setSubject(subject);
                    email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                    email.setPlainTextBody(body + 'Click The Followoing Link http://tefllife.com/studentfeedback.html');
                    try
                   {
                     Messaging.SendEmailResult [] resultMail= Messaging.sendEmail(new 

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
                     if(resultMail[0].isSuccess())       
                     response = 'ok sent!';
                      else
                      {
                         response = resultMail[0].getErrors().get(0).getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                    catch(System.EmailException ex)
                    {
                      response = ex.getMessage();
                    }   
                }

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

apex page is:

```
<apex:page controller="SendEmailToFeedback" id="thePage">
<script>
function confirmCancel() {
var isCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
if (isCancel) return true;
return false;
}
</script>
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >

        <p>Fill out the fields below to test how you might send an email to a Opportunity.</p><br />
        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opp}" var="o" border="1">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                {!o.Name}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Email</apex:facet>
                 {!o.Email__c}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" for="Subject"/>:<br />
        <apex:inputText value="{!subject}" id="Subject" maxlength="80"/>
        <br /><br />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Body" for="Body"/>:<br />
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!body}" id="Body" rows="10" cols="80"/>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <apex:commandButton value="SendEmail" action="{!send}"/> 
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"
        onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy Apex code to a sandbox without unit tests, however deploying to production instance requires you to write unit tests for your Apex code.

More info [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm#kanchor441)

Also, deploying to production requires at least 75% code coverage from your unit tests.